# Is there a Firefox Tab like IE Tab?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, activex

IE Tab allows users to view pages using the IE rendering engine. Is there something along these lines the other way around, rendering a tab using Gecko in IE?

Is it possible to write an ActiveX control to include the Gecko engine or webkit and use that to render the page?

Comment: I think you should try super user rather than stack overflow for this type of question

Answer (score 1):

You could write an ActiveX control to do this.  However, I suspect it would be much harder to host Gecko in IE than to host IE in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's true, but IE 8 seems to have some similar feature:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/03/31/breaking-internet-explorer-81-eagle-eyes-leaked/

Comment: Good link ... but a quote seems wrong: "IE 8.1 kicks major butt in the Acid3 Test scoring 71 out of 100, passing with flying colors."  How exactly is a 71% == passing with flying colors? LOL